# For Loop syntax error -one click goes through entire loop

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, for-loop, conditional-statements

As a novice in javascript, I think I have a simple issue.

- *edit* I wanted an event to happen ( the two buttons appearing) after a user clicks an option from the drop box 3 times. I initially thought the for loop would help me do that. I also wanted the last choice ("None" or Other option) to display the warning and not effect the number of turns you have left to click. Hope that makes more sense.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var question1 = new Array(); 

window.onload = function () {
    var eSelect = document.getElementById('question1');
    var optOtherReason = document.getElementById('displayresponse');
    var options = document.getElementsByTagName("option");

    eSelect.onchange = function() {
        for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
            if (eSelect.selectedIndex !== 3) {
                    var li = document.createElement("li");
                    li.innerHTML = options[eSelect.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
                    var ol = document.getElementById("appendedtext");
                    ol.appendChild(li);         

                question1.push(li.innerHTML);
                var x= document.getElementById("display");
                x.innerHTML=question1;  
            }
        } 
        if (eSelect.selectedIndex == 3) {
            i=0;
            optOtherReason.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
    insertbutton= "block";
    displaybutton = "block";
}

<select id="question1" name="question">
    <option value="x">Reason1</option>
    <option value="y">Reason2</option>
    <option value="other">Otherreason</option>
    <option value="none">None</option>
</select><br>

<div id="insertbutton" style="display:none;">
    <input type="button"  value="Save" onclick="insert();">
</div>

<div id="generatebutton" style="display:none;">
    <input type="button" value="Show Drink" onClick="generate();">
</div>

<div id="displayresponse" style="display:none;">If you did not see a choice here, you may search for other sites.</div>

<ol id="appendedtext"> </ol>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: I don’t get what you’re asking here … of course that for loop will run three times, but I suppose that is not the surprise here? First of all, have you checked whether your first if condition in there yields true when you _expect_ it to via a debug output? For example via `console.log(eSelect.selectedIndex, eSelect.selectedIndex !== 3)` before the if (check your browser’s JS console afterwards).

Comment: The <select> element will only return one value so there is no need for the loop. As CBroe stated: check the eSelect.selectedIndex value to return with item was selected.

Comment: I was looking for a way to initiate an event (buttons appearing) after the user clicked an option from the drop down menu three times. I was under the impression that a loop would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you need to loop through the options since you are accessing the index directly. This seems like what you are looking for :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var question1 = new Array(); 

window.onload = function() {
var eSelect = document.getElementById('question1');
var optOtherReason = document.getElementById('displayresponse');
var options = document.getElementsByTagName("option");

eSelect.onchange = function() {

    //for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    if (eSelect.selectedIndex !== 3) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = options[eSelect.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    var ol = document.getElementById("appendedtext");
    ol.appendChild(li);         

    question1.push(li.innerHTML);
    var x= document.getElementById("display");
    x.innerHTML=question1;  
    }
    //} 
 if (eSelect.selectedIndex == 3){
        //i=0;
        optOtherReason.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
    insertbutton= "block";
        displaybutton = "block";
} 
</script>
<select id="question1" name="question">
<option value="x">Reason1</option>
<option value="y">Reason2</option>
<option value="other">Otherreason</option>
<option value="none">None</option>
</select><br>

<div id="insertbutton" style="display:none;">
<input type="button"  value="Save" onclick="insert();"></div>

<div id="generatebutton" style="display:none;">
<input type="button" value="Show Drink" onClick="generate();"></div>

<div id="displayresponse" style="display:none;">If you did not see a choice here, you may search for other sites.</div>

<ol id="appendedtext"> </ol>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to initiate an event (buttons appearing) after the user clicked an option from the drop down menu three times. I was under the impression that a loop would help.

Comment: Okay, what you need is a counter then. Let me know if the logic below is correct so that I can help with the code :
if user selects a particular option, set counter=1.
if user selects the same option again, increment counter.
if counter =3, initiate button.

Comment: I declared "turns" as a global variable "var turns= 0", and then made it add an increment by one when a user chose anything besides the last choice."turns= turns +1;" Finally when "turns" incremented to 4, I set it so that the buttons displayed "if (turns= 4)" {} . For some reasons the button will not display

Comment: use "if (turns==4)" instead of "if (turns=4)"

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Don, I don't think the for loop is necessary.  One minor difference I would make would be checking the selected value instead of the index, since it's easy for drop-down lists to have their ordering changed.  Also, it's cleaner to use if-else instead of two if's.

```
var question1 = new Array(); 

window.onload = function() {
var eSelect = document.getElementById('question1');
var optOtherReason = document.getElementById('displayresponse');
var options = document.getElementsByTagName("option");

eSelect.onchange = function() {
var optOtherReason = document.getElementById('displayresponse');
var options = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
    if (eSelect.value !== "other") {   // For loop eliminated, checking value now
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = options[eSelect.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
        var ol = document.getElementById("appendedtext");
        ol.appendChild(li);         

        question1.push(li.innerHTML);
        var x= document.getElementById("display");
        x.innerHTML=question1;  
    }else{    // Using else here
        optOtherReason.style.display = 'block';
    }
    }
    insertbutton= "block";
    displaybutton = "block";
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to initiate an event (buttons appearing) after the user clicked an option from the drop down menu three times. I was under the impression that a loop would help.

Comment: I think you'd want to maintain click count then.  Am I understanding the task correctly?